# Vertically Stack divs inside fixed div

Tags: css, layout, positioning

I have a vertical parent container div with fixed positioning and height in pixels. I have child divs with same width as the parent. How do i stack these child divs inside the fixed parent? I am uanble to get through. please help.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies.
My problem is that my container has a fixed height in pixels. It is not dynamically resizing. the height is fixed. I want my childern to be stacked(bottom up) like you put dishes in a bucket. normally the children stick to the top. I want my childeren to sink to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it statically, just set each child div's top property how you want it.

So if those child divs are 50px in height

```
#child1{
position:relative;
top:50px;
}
#child2{
position:relative;  
top:100px;
}
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

They should already be stacked. Could you elaborate on your problem?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="stack one"></div>
    <div class="stack two"></div>
    <div class="stack three"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 250px;
}

.stack {
    width: 250px; height: 100px;
}

.one { background: red; }
.two { background: green; }
.three { background: orange; }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eUj83/)

**Updated** -

After reading your reply, I've now updated the CSS - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eUj83/1/)

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px; height: 300px;
}

.stack {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px; height: 100px;
}

.one { background: red; bottom: 0; }
.two { background: green; bottom: 100px; }
.three { background: orange; bottom: 200px; }
```